# PHP: What does "a or b" expression mean?

Tags: php

Came across this code:

```
<?php
require_once 'HTTP/Session/Container/DB.php';

$s = new HTTP_Session_Container_DB('mysql://user:password@localhost/db'); 

ini_get('session.auto_start') or session_start();  //HERE. ?? 

?>
```

What does this kind of express mean in PHP? [ a OR b] ?

```
ini_get('session.auto_start') or session_start();
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if (!ini_get('session.auto_start')) session_start();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That expression relies upon the way the `or` works. It's usually used to check if either one of two booleans are true:

```
$foo = true or false // true
$foo = false or false // false
```

The cool thing is that if the left part of the `or` is true, it never checks the latter part because it doesn't need to. That means that you can put an expression on each side of the `or`. If the left part results in a negative value (a value that resolves to `false`) then the right part will be executed. If the left part results in a positive value, one that resolves to true, then the right part will never be executed.

So to summarize, this:

```
ini_get('session.auto_start') or session_start();
```

is identical to this:

```
if(!ini_get('session.auto_start')) session_start();
```

since `ini_get('session.auto_start')` results in either `0` or `1`, which evaluates to `false` and `true` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword `or` is the "logical or" operator, equivalent to `||`:

```
if ($x < 0 or $y < 0) // the same as:
if ($x < 0 || $y < 0)
```

A property of `or` is that the second operand is not evaluated if the first one returns true:

```
  if (!isset($var) || $var === null)
#                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                     This code is never run if !isset($var) returns false.
```

This can be (mis)used to write "do something or handle the error" code:

```
  do_something() or handle_error()
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# If do_something() returns true, there is no error to handle, 
# and handle_error() is never executed.
```

It could be written more clearly using an explicit `if`:

```
if (!do_something())
    handle_error();
```

Comment: I would disagree that this way of using the `or` operator is misuse since it's actually quite readable. "Either succeed in doing **x** OR do **y**"

Comment: This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Many programming languages support it.

Answer (score 2):

if `a` resolves to a value, which PHP can convert to `true`, then `b` won't be executed.

It can be used as a shortcut for `if( !a ) b`

Answer (score 1):

Do function A, if it fails do function B

you can usually see this on mysql_query("jibberish") or die('mysql couldnt run query');

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if session.auto_start is set to true, do nothing. Else, start the session.

a OR b checks if a is true and if not executes b.

So basicaly, this means, start session only if it's not started by default.